# describe( ) method gives false 75% quantile

Tags: pandas, statistics, quantile, describe

```
Xi = pd.DataFrame([("Guyana", 5.78, 6.89), ("Paraguay", 7.29, 8.5), ("Ecuador", 9.35, 10.92), ("Peru", 9.96, 11.55), ("Kolumbien", 10.9, 12.71), 
                   ("Costa Rica", 13.0, 14.27), ("Brasilien", 14.4, 15.23), ("Venezuela", 16.56, 16.77), ("Argentina", 18.71, 18.8), ("Chile", 19.36, 21.92)], columns=["country", "GDP/L 2010", "GDP/L 2014"])
Xi.describe()
```

So obviously the 75% quantile is (N+1)*3/4 which gives us Xi with i = 8,25. So the 75% quantile for 2010 equals 17,635 and not like the describe() method outputs 16,02.
Why is that?

Comment: you calculation is unclear, what is `N` and `i = 8,25` and how do you get `17.635`?

Comment: N = 10 since we got 10 countries. i = (N+1)*3/4 and because there is no 8,25th datapoint we take the mean of (X8+X9)/2. Maybe it is due to the fact that the df starts to count with 0, but I calculated it, I am not getting 16,02.

Comment: If should be `(N-1)*3/4` as python counts from **0**. See my answer for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into it and for some reason it seems that both functions describe() and quantile(0.75) return the wrong value of the percentile 75%. Even more, they return the correct percentile 75% if the last row did not exist (these methods are not taking into account the last row).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think your interpretation of the quantile is incorrect.

Starting from this sorted Series:

```
s = Xi['GDP/L 2010']
print(s)

0     5.78
1     7.29
2     9.35
3     9.96
4    10.90
5    13.00
6    14.40
7    16.56
8    18.71
9    19.36
```

The 0.75 quantile is computed using the 0.75th value if any of the values before and after.

Here We have 10 elements, and python starts counting from zero, so the wanted index (assuming sorted values!) is:

```
(len(Xi)-1)*3/4 # 6.75
```

There is not 6.75 so we have many possibilities to get the quantile

```
# closest index
# closest is 7 so the quantile is
16.56

# mid-point: (14.40+16.56)/2
15.48

# linear interpolation
# as the index is 6.75 weighted mean of 14.40 and 16.56
16.020
```

By default, [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) is using the linear interpolation. You can change it  using the `interpolation` parameter:

```
s = Xi['GDP/L 2010']

s.quantile(0.75, interpolation='linear')
# 16.02

s.quantile(0.75, interpolation='nearest')
# 16.56

s.quantile(0.75, interpolation='midpoint')
# 15.48
```

Comment: Ok good to know. But I learned to calculate the quantiles like that:                                             we got a Xi column where i is the index for the number of characteristics. If we want to calculate the quantiles we do: i = (N+1) * 1/4 for 1. quantile, (N+1) * 1/2 for median, (N+1) * 3/4 for 3. quantile. If I do it like this and starting the index i = 1 and not i = 0 like python I get: i = (10+1) * 3/4 which is 8,25. So I take the mean of X8 and X9.

Comment: So X8 = 16,56 and X9 = 18,71 since the cumulative percentages reach 70% at the 8th and 84% at the 9th the 75% quantile must be between them, doesnt it?